# Populate Multiple combobox's makes VBA userform slow

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, multiple-columns

At the moment I'm working with making a userform with 40 combobox's all which have the same list. My problem is filling all those combobox's is making the `userform.show` slow. The list that gets populated in those combobox's is a very long list (46542 rows and list length can vary) the list is with 3 columns.

I have been fooling around with CONCATENATE the whole list but that doesn't make much of a change. Also because I need to have the value when selected in the combobox to be CONCATENATE with all 3 columns in the combobox etc. when selecting row no. 1 in the combobox instead of writing only column 1 in the comboxbox textfield it will return all 3 columns so that means I'm actually having 4 columns where the first is CONCATENATE and hidden in the dropdown.

So my question is, is there a way to do the process more light?

So here is the code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Set tsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Players")
Dim v As Variant, i As Long
v = tsheet.Range("A2:l" & Worksheets("Players").Cells(Rows.Count, 
1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
With Me.ComboBox1
.RowSource = ""
.ColumnCount = 4
.BoundColumn = 2
.ColumnWidths = "1;50;50;50" 'Hide first column in dropdown
For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
.AddItem v(i, 1) & " " & v(i, 2) & " " & v(i, 3)
.List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = v(i, 1)
.List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = v(i, 2)
.List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = v(i, 3)
Next i
End With
With Me.ComboBox2
.RowSource = ""
.ColumnCount = 4
.BoundColumn = 2
.ColumnWidths = "1;50;50;50" 'Hide first column in dropdown
For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
.AddItem v(i, 1) & " " & v(i, 2) & " " & v(i, 3)
.List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = v(i, 1)
.List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = v(i, 2)
.List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = v(i, 3)
Next i
End With
```

This code goes on until it hit combox40

My old code was working pretty fast but it didn't have the column that was concatenated

```
ComboBox3.ColumnWidths = "50;50;50"         'COLUMN WITH OF LISTBOX
ComboBox3.ColumnCount = 3                                                 
'COLUMN NUMBER OF LISTBOX
ComboBox3.List = tsheet.Range("A2:l" & 
Worksheets("Players").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

Comment: do not define `tsheet` and then use `Worksheets("Players")` in your code .... use `tsheet`

Comment: there is no need to define `.RowSource` `.ColumnCount` `.BoundColumn` `.ColumnWidths` properties at run time .... those values are saved with the workbook .... set those in a separate subroutine that you run only once and then save the workbook.  rerun the sub if you want to make any changes to those values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
ComboBox3.List = tsheet.Range("A2:l" & 
Worksheets("Players").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

use something like this (declare Arr as Variant):-

```
Arr = tsheet.Range("A2:l" & 
Worksheets("Players").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
' add your extra rows to the array here, followed by
ComboBox3.List = Arr
```

Instead of repeating the same code 40 times, create a loop.

```
For i = 1 to 40
    Cbx = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & Cstr(i))
    ' then manipulate Cbx as you have done.
Next I
```

Finally, since your 40 comboboxes are all the same, why not make do with only 1? You can move it around from row to row, let the user make his selection and transfer that selection to a textbox that appears in the place of the Cbx on Exit. When you click on the Tbx again it is substituted by the Cbx so that you have access to the list again.

Comment: Hi Variatus thanks for your input. if I understand you right and i'm not so sure of that :) then that is not possible with the moving around because there is no textbox there is only the dropdown and when I say textfield I mean the textfield of the combobox the reason I have 40 of them is because when the user choose something in all of them and press a save button all those combox's textfields are transferred to a sheet.

the userform is like this : its a startsheet for golf meaning all the combobox have a list with all players then he choose player for each starts position therefore 40 Cbx

Comment: but thx for the code above I will see if I can get that to work I makes good sense to make it like that thx for taking the time to help mate ;) I was really not sure how to make that loop for combobox

Comment: If you have a Tbx and a Cbx of identical size in precisely the same position the one on top will be all the user can see or use. You might hide one of the controls for good measure or because the Cbx isn't really needed until you need it. So, you have 40 Tbx. When the user clicks any of them the Cbx appears in its place. When he clicks somewhere else the result of the Cbx is transferred to the Tbx underneath it and the Cbx either disappears or reappears in the place of the Tbx the user clicked.

Comment: Now I get it and the hole loading of the userform is much faster very nice thx a lot !

Answer (score 1):

use the `RowSource` property of the combobox control

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim tsheet As Worksheet
    Set tsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Players")

    Dim rs As String
    rs = "Players!a2:d" & tsheet.Cells(tsheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim aaa As Control
    For Each aaa In Me.Controls
        If Left(aaa.Name, 8) = "ComboBox" Then
            aaa.RowSource = rs                ' =mySheet!a2:d24 in properties
            aaa.ControlSource = "Players!z1"  ' put the chosen value into this cell (example)
            aaa.ColumnCount = 4
            aaa.BoundColumn = 2
            aaa.ColumnWidths = "1;50;50;50"   ' Hide first column in dropdown
        End If
    Next aaa

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In the module:

```
Dim ArrPlayers() as integer
```

In the userform initialization:

```
'To Do: add code to populate listbox with players
ReDim ArrPlayers (0 To 39)
```

On the listbox change event:

```
txtPosition.text = ArrPlayers(lstPlayers.ListIndex)
```

On the textbox change event:

```
ArrPlayers(lstPlayers.ListIndex) = cInt(txtPosition.text)
```

You will need to then save the values.