# How to create a generic combobox fill routine in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to have a generic method for filling combo boxes in Microsoft Visual Basic for Application 7.1.

I tried to cast a control parameter to comboBox with `CType` but Excel doesn't recognize this function.

How can I fill a comboBox in a generic way?

Comment: if you fill the comboBox from a worksheet range, then you can use the `RowSource` property .  ... example here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389412/excel-vba-userform-populate-multiple-comboboxs-makes-userform-slow/46393353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is through the name of the ComboBox. You do not have to cast a `control` to `comboBox`.

```vb
Public Sub FillComboBox(UserForm As UserForm, cbName As String, column As String, startRow As Integer)
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Count As Integer
    Set dataSheet = Worksheets("yourWorksheetName")

    Count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(dataSheet.Range(column & startRow & ":" & column & "10000")) - 1
    UserForm.Controls(cbName).List = dataSheet.Range(column & startRow & ":" & column & startRow + Count).value
End Sub
```

The call in your UserForm or wherever looks like this:

```vb
FillComboBox Me, Me.cbMyComboBox.name, "A", 1
```

Comment: Rather than passing both the form and the combobox name, couldn't you just pass the combobox itself as the parameter?  (i.e. `FillComboBox Me.cbMyComboBox, "A"` to call the procedure, and then just have `Public Sub FillComboBox(cb As ComboBox, column As String)` as the procedure declaration.  (P.S.  Did you really intend to subtract one from the count?  That will leave out the last value in the column.  Or maybe the last line of code was meant to start at row 2 to ignore a header in row 1?)

Comment: @YowE3K I edit my post. I thought he need a function to convert a string to an object. A lightly "reflection" ;-)

Comment: I think I see what you were thinking now.  I can see the use for passing the name (if the OP had an array of the names it would be especially useful) but the question implies that the OP already has a reference to the control, so using the reference to the control in order to get the control's name to order to get back to a reference to the control seems "convoluted" to me.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I have some labels `l{name}` with associated comboBox `cb{name}`. Now I can write something like that: `UserForm.Controls("cb" & Right(labelName, Len(labelName) - 1))`